# Eclipse RCP handle CustomMigration Exceptions

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have a model in an Eclipse RCP application. Sometimes a new model version is created, so the existing model gets migrated. This can be done by implementing the CustomMigration class. This migration takes place when opening the model file with a editor implementation.

If this migration fails for some reason, the model can not be migrated. The problem is, in this case the editor is still being opened, but this will not work because there is no valid model. This will cause a mess like a broken editor window and exceptions.
How can this mess be avoided? Is there a reason to abort the opening process of the editor? Or is it possible to do the migration before the window is opened?

Comment: I'm really not sure what your are asking. An `IEditorPart` `init` method can throw a `PartInitException` to abort editor initialization.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is the solution. Throwing the PartInitException to abort the initialisation does the job. There are no broken editors or wild exceptions anymore.